# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory is working fine in the system while i uploading plugin on CRM, its showing an error

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, azure-devops, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

I am using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`. It's working as required in the Console application. While I am uploading it on CRM by converting it to plugin, it's throwing this error. I have ILmerge all dll but `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.platform.dll` is not merging with it and throwing duplication dll error. Please suggest the solution.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

In the plugin model, authentication to D365 is handled internally and the context gives you an IOrganizationService that is already authenticated.

You do not have to ILMerge any MSFT D365 or AD libraries to get a plugin working with D365 data.

You would only have to do ILMerge if you had an external library. And please note that ILMerge is technically [unsupported](http://www.develop1.net/public/post/2018/10/21/ILMergeNotSupported) in plugins.

If you are authenticating to Azure you might want to look into doing an [Azure-aware plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/write-custom-azure-aware-plugin) instead.